# WPF line alignment

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, alignment, richtextbox

How can I create a `TextBox`/`RichTextBox` (or maybe a custom `UserControl`) in `WPF` with different align between each line ?

As you can see in Facebook's inbox, your text is aligned on the right and your friend's text is aligned on the left

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about FlowDocument?

```
<FlowDocument>
    <Paragraph  TextAlignment="Right">
        Rigth
    </Paragraph>
    <Paragraph  TextAlignment="Left">
        Left
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer create two different paragraphs. How can I make the line interleave each other

Comment: What does interleave mean?

Comment: i think your answer is easy to use.

Comment: If you create 2 paragraphs, all line of paragraph 1 will be above all line of paragraph 2. But what I really want is the line with different align can stack with each other (hope you can understand it)

Comment: I think my picture is clearly enough and I also said that I want it to looked like Facebook's inbox

Comment: Too bad I'm in China and have no access to FaceBook : <, may be you can wait for Mark Zuckerberg to give the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. WPF natively supports applying different styles to alternate items.
2. ItemsControl.AlternationIndex enables you to do this.
3. Apply AlternationCount `<ListBox AlternationCount="2">`.
4. Define styles like this :

   ```
   <Style  TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
      <Style.Triggers>
       <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"
                Value="0">
           <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                   Value="Right"></Setter>
       </Trigger>
       <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex"
                Value="1">
           <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                   Value="Left"></Setter>
       </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
   </Style>
   ```

Experiment with above concept.

Comment: Could you please be more specific. I don't know how to use it

Comment: @Fish Learn WPF first.